# Correct design using dependency inversion principle across modules?

Tags: solid-principles, dependency-inversion

I understand dependency inversion when working inside a single module, but I would like to also apply it when I have a cross-module dependency. In the following diagrams I have an existing application and I need to implement some new requirements for reference data services. I thought I will create a new jar (potentially a stand-alone service in the future). The first figure shows the normal way I have approached such things in the past. The referencedataservices jar has an interface which the app will use to invoke it.

The second figure shows my attempt to use DIP, the app now owns its abstraction so it is not subject to change just because the reference data service changes. This seems to be a wrong design though, because it creates a circular dependency. MyApp depends on referencedataservices jar, and referencedataservices jar depends on MyApp.

So the third figure gets back to the more normal dependency by creating an extra layer of abstraction. Am I right? Or is this really not what DIP was intended for? Interested in hearing about other approaches or advice.

, [image: dependency inversion diagrams]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second example is on the right track by separating the implementation from its abstraction. To achieve modularity, a concrete class should not be in the same package (module) as its abstract interface.

The fault in the second example is that the client owns the abstraction, while the service owns the implementation. These two roles must be reversed: services own interfaces; clients own implementations. In this way, the service presents a contract (API) for the client to implement. The service guarantees interaction with any client that adheres to its API. In terms of dependency inversion, the client injects a dependency into the service.

Kirk K. is something of an authority on modularity in Java. He had a blog that eventually turned into a [book](http://www.kirkk.com/modularity/) on the subject. His blog seems to be missing at the moment, but I was able to find it in the Wayback Machine. I think you would be particularly interested in the four-part series titled [Applied Modularity](https://web.archive.org/web/20130502125759/http://techdistrict.kirkk.com/2009/11/16/applied-modularity-part-1/). In terms of other approaches or alternatives to DIP, take a look at [Fun With Modules](https://web.archive.org/web/20130502134019/http://techdistrict.kirkk.com/2010/01/12/fun-with-modules/), which covers three of them.

Answer (score 0):

In second approach that you presented, if you move `RefDataSvc` abstraction to separate package you break the cycle and `referencedataservices` package use only package with `RefDataSvc` abstraction.

Other code apart from [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) in `MyApp` package should depend also on `RefDataSvc`. In [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) of your application you should then compose all dependencies that are needed in your app.